# htaccess: Folder Move

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I want to move a Folder and all subfolders to another root.

Example:

```
http://www.example.de/de/product1
```

to:

```
http://www.example.de/product1
```

I want to realize this via .htaccess .. I only wanna move "/de/" and everything that follows after "/de/" to the Root via 301 Redirect.

So if a User/Bot request http://www.example.de/de/product3 there will be a Redirect to http://www.example.de/product3

Also if a User/Bot request http://www.example.de/de/product3/details there will be a Redirect to http://www.example.de/product3/details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redirect directive to rediret everything inside **/de** folder to root.

```
Redirect /de/ /
```

This will  redirect **/de/foobar** to **/foobar** using 302 Default redirect status .

You can also set a **301** argument in Redirect ,this makes the redirect permanent

```
Redirect 301 /de/ /
```